# caption shortcode inserts blank paragraph

Tags: images

> [NOTE: Cross-posted from wordpress.org/support/topic/caption-shortcode-inserts-blank-paragraph to see which site gets a better answer. :]

I am setting up a new blog, no plugins yet. I inserted a photo in to a post, align right, with a caption. When I view the post in The zen light theme or the default theme I get a blank paragraph rendered above the image. Why is that and how can I change that?

See: http://www.the99ers.net/2010/09/hello/

The relevant code reads:

`<p><div id="attachment_19"`

Basically, I am pretty sure I want to drop the outer `<p>` and just have the `<div>` float where it needs to go.  Why is it doing what it is doing and how can I make it down what I want?  Thanks!

Sincerely,
-danny

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is something got trimmed from the markup inserted in to the post.  I switched to the HTML editor, deleted and reinserted the shortcode, and everything looked fine.